# jquery on event not working on phonegap but chrome works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

jquery **on** event not working for class that is append after document ready on phonegap. but it's working fine on chrome.

my template code is here:

```
    <script type="text/template" id="newsList">
        <div class="news-list" news_id="{3}">
            <div class="news-list-title">
                <span>{0}</span> | {1}
            </div>
            <div class="news-list-text">{2}</div>
            <span class="news-list-more">Oku</span>
        </div>
    </script>
```

render method:

```
    var template = $("#newsList").html();
    var str = "";
    for(var i in data[page]){
        str += template.format(data[page][i]['created_at'], data[page][i]['title'], data[page][i]['content'], data[page][i]['id']);
    }
    $("#news-list-wrapper").html(str);
```

and event code:

```
    var app = {
        initalize: function(){
            var _this = this;
            $(document).on("click", ".news-list", function(){
                _this.openNews($(this).attr("news_id"));
            });
        }
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){
            app.initialize();
        },false);
    });
```

my jquery version is 1.9.1 and i tried 2.1.0

and i tried these;

```
    $(document).on("click", ".news-list", function(){....
    $(".news-list").on("click", function(){....
    $(document).delegate("click", ".news-list", function(){....
    $(".news-list").live("click", function(){....
```

Comment: move ur click code from initalize to document.ready and try

Comment: didn't work... $(document).ready(function(){ $(document).on("click", ".news-list", function(){